# Double opt-in link with Subscriber Key as a parameter

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm trying to configure a double opt-in link for a subscriber list. The double op-in link works perfectly only if email address is used as the subscriber key in ExactTarget. What if we have a custom subscriber key. for example '1022-myemail@work.com'

Double Opt-in link URL: http://cl.exct.net/sub_confirm.asp?lst=%%List_%%&eml=%%EmailAddr_%%&mid=%%MemberID%%

Is there a way we could pass subscriber key as a parameter in the double opt in link?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that double opt in link only works if subscriber key is same as email address. 
I have to write a custom Ampscript on a microsite to update subscriber status.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the subscriber key is on in your account (which it obviously is) you need %%_subscriberkey%% .  See http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/personalization_strings/

for the list of available substitution strings.

Comment: where shall I pass %%_subscriberkey%% in the double opt-in link?? Whats the brand tag for subscriber key? [http://cl.exct.net/sub_confirm.asp?lst=%%List_%%&eml=%%EmailAddr_%%&mid=%%MemberID%%]

Comment: First question:  it doesn't matter where it is in the link.   2nd: I don't think brandtag applies.  Brandtags generally go across all subscribers in the account and are on a per account basis; obviously subscriberkey is for just 1.

Comment: I dont understand.this is the link for double opt in http://cl.exct.net/sub_confirm.asp?lst=%%List_%%&eml=%%EmailAddr_%%&mid=%%MemberID%%. Now where shall I pass %%_subscriberkey%% in the query string for the subscriber status to change from unsubscribed to Active? for more in here is the link to configuring double opt in http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/lists_for_interactive_marketing_hub/creating_a_list/configuring_a_list_for_double_opt_in/